# non-capturing group in regular expressions

Tags: regex

**This is my string:**

> **Remediation**
>
> Upgrade codecov to version 3.6.5 or higher.
>
> **References**
>
> GitHub Commit

**This is my Regex:**

```
(?=Remediation)[^\n]*[\s\S]*?(?=References|$)
```

**Match Output:**

> Remediation Upgrade codecov to version 3.6.5 or higher.

I do not need the heading("**Remediation**") in the output. I have put `?=` in the group, but so far it doesn't work.

How could I do this?

Comment: why not just replace `Remediation` with blank char ?

Comment: I have many more headings, but I only need the contents between "remediation" and "references".

Comment: what language re you using ?

Comment: What language/tool are you using? From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pattern you start with a `(?=` wich is a postivive lookahead assertion.

One option is to update the pattern to change it to a positive lookbehind. You can omit `[^\n]*` as the following `[\s\S]*?` will also match it.

```
(?<=Remediation)[\s\S]*?(?=References)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xJd9Ns/1)

Another option is to match Remedations and capture in a group all lines that do not start with References unsing a negative lookahead.

```
\bRemediation\s*\r?\n((?:(?!References).*)+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ITMyEc/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:Remediation\s*)([\s\S]*?)(?:\s+References)
```

will do the trick.
(?:) is none-capturing. You also probably do not want to capture the whitespaces after Remediation or before References, so I am adding \s* to the none-capturing groups. [demo](https://regex101.com/r/sJtkW1/1)

or per the comment, you can eliminate the none capturing syntax and just do:

```
Remediation\s*([\s\S]*?)\s+References
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/sJtkW1/2)

here you take group 1

Comment: Non capture group is useless here.